# Empathy Internet Messaging Error [No reason specified]

Tags: internet, empathy

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.
Empathy Internet Messaging was working fine until yesterday. Now it's showing an error under every email with

> [ No reason specified ]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add an answer and accept it. That way others can see that the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your network, and if your proxy is on **manual** or **automatic**, set it to **none**.

That's what worked for me.